# Revert password back to original

Tags: password

I changed my password a while back, and now want to change it back to THE ORIGINAL PASSWORD. But it says it is not strong enough. What can I do?

(I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a lenovo think pad.)

Comment: You can boot into recovery mode, open terminal, and run `sudo passwd "username"` and that will let you change the password. I don't think `passwd` cares how long the password is. Sidenote: you may need to re-mount the main drive to make it writeable. It's defaulted to non-write mode while in recovery. `mount -o remount,rw /` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command

```
sudo passwd <your username>
```

This is does not  check for security, so it should let you change your password to the one before.